# Validate Json schema based on the value specified for a property

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a Json request having the below data and a corresponding json schema for it

With this request, I want to make a few fields as required depending on the mode

Say if mode is 1, then I want the fields a and b in obj1 to be required and field x in obj3 as required.
Now if the mode is 2, I would want fields p, q and r in obj2 to be required, fields a and c in obj1 as required and field y in obj3 as required.
Next if the mode is 3, I want only fields a and c as required

Json request

```
{
  "mode": "1",
  "obj1": {
      "a": 12,
      "b": "test",
      "c": "18 June 2019"
      },
 "obj2": {
      "p": 100,
      "q": "new",
      "r": "19 June 2019",
      "s" : "test2"
      },
  "obj3": {
      "x": 12,
      "y": "test3"
      }
}


**Json schema**
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "mode": {
      "$id": "#/properties/mode",
      "type": "string",
      "examples": [
        "1"
      ]
    },
    "obj1": {
      "$id": "#/properties/obj1",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Obj 1 Schema",
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj1/properties/a",
          "type": "integer",
          "examples": [
            12
          ]
        },
        "b": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj1/properties/b",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "test"
          ]
        },
        "c": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj1/properties/c",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "18 June 2019"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "obj 2": {
      "$id": "#/properties/obj2",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Obj 2 Schema",
      "properties": {
        "p": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj2/properties/p",
          "type": "integer",
          "examples": [
            100
          ]
        },
        "q": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj2/properties/q",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "new"
          ]
        },
        "r": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj2/properties/r",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "19 June 2019"
          ]
        },
        "s": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj2/properties/s",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "test2"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "obj 3": {
      "$id": "#/properties/obj3",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Obj 3 Schema",
      "properties": {
        "x": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj3/properties/x",
          "type": "integer",
          "examples": [
            12
          ]
        },
        "y": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj3/properties/y",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "test3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT - Changed the schema to validate based on the suggestion by @gregsdennis

JSON SCHEMA

```
    {
      "definitions": {},
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "mode": {
          "$id": "#/properties/mode",
          "type": "string",
          "examples": [
            "1"
          ]
        },
        "obj1": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj1",
          "type": "object",
          "title": "The Obj 1 Schema",
          "properties": {
            "a": {
              "type": "integer",
              "examples": [
                12
              ]
            },
            "b": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "test"
              ]
            },
            "c": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "18 June 2019"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "obj 2": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj2",
          "type": "object",
          "title": "The Obj 2 Schema",
          "properties": {
            "p": {
              "type": "integer",
              "examples": [
                100
              ]
            },
            "q": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "new"
              ]
            },
            "r": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "19 June 2019"
              ]
            },
            "s": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "test2"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "obj 3": {
          "$id": "#/properties/obj3",
          "type": "object",
          "title": "The Obj 3 Schema",
          "properties": {
            "x": {
              "type": "integer",
              "examples": [
                12
              ]
            },
            "y": {
              "type": "string",
              "examples": [
                "test3"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
"oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "mode": {"const": 1},
        "obj1": {"required": ["a","b"]},
        "obj3": {"required": ["x"]}
       }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "mode": {"const": 2},
        "obj2": {"required": ["p","q","r"]},
        "obj1": {"required": ["a","c"]},
        "obj3": {"required": ["y"]}
       }
    }
]
    }
```

So, in brief, irrespective of how many modes, fields or objects I have, I would like only a few selected fields from different objects to be required at a given time for a particular mode.
Can anyone please suggest any solutions to achieve this? Is it possible to have such validations in the json schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an `oneOf` where each subschema gives a valid state for each of `obj*` properties.  Each state would be something like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "mode": {"const": 1},
    "obj1": {"required": ["a","b"]},
    "obj3": {"required": ["x"]}
  }
}
```

Create one of these for each of the states you listed in your question, and throw them all in a `oneOf` that lives at the root.

You *could* do this with `if`/`then`/`else`, but for this case, I'd prefer the `oneOf` to avoid nesting.

---

Also, I notice that you have a lot of superfluous `$id`s in the middle that are just specifying their location within the schema.  You want the one at the root, but you don't need the others.  Implementations can work out these kinds of location-based references trivially.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gregsdennis. Although I understood the approach that you suggested, I wanted to clarify if this is exactly what you meant. Can U please take a look at the schema posted by me as an edit?

Comment: Yeah, that looks right for modes 1 and 2. You'd need an entry for each mode.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again @gregsdennis